# Compare jar certificates in a directory

Tags: java, groovy, jar, spock

I'm writing unit tests to compare the signature of Jar certificates. I am stuck on how to provide the file path to the JarFile : as of right now, it seems to be returning some sort of hashed name.

```
String[] jarClasses2 = dir2.list()
    for (int i = 0; i < jarClasses2.length; i++) {
    String jarName = jarClasses2[i]
    String filePath="pos/lib2/"+jarName
    JarFile jarFile1=new JarFile(filePath)
    JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(filePath)
    Certificate cert = entry.getCertificates()
    JarEntry entry=jarFile.entries()
    assertNotNull(cert)
}
```

My file path is correct but when I print the name of jarFile, it is: "java.util.jar.JarFile@1e66f1f5." I also receive an exception when trying to cast the jar file to JarEntry:

> *org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'java.util.jar.JarFile$JarEntryIterator@7530ad9c' with class 'java.util.jar.JarFile$JarEntryIterator' to class 'java.util.jar.JarEntry'

**Any suggestions on how to get the jar location and cast it correctly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see a cast exception is that `.entries()` returns

```
Enumeration <JarEntry>
```

not just a single `JarEntry`.  So rather than

```
    JarEntry entry=jarFile.entries()
```

you would need something like:

```
    Enumeration<JarEntry> entries=jarFile.entries()

    while(entries.hasMoreElements()) {
       JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement()
       Certificate[] certificates = entry.getCertificates()
       // process certificates in this jar entry
    }
```

(See [JarFile#entries()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#entries--) and [JarEntry#getCertificates()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarEntry.html#getCertificates--)).

Comment: Ignoring that, is there an issue with the jarFile not returning the actual name of the jar, or is that not a problem?

Comment: In the code above, you already seem to know the name of the jar (the `jarName` variable). I don't think I follow what you're trying to do.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Just saw the edited code -- thanks for clarifying!

Comment: No problem. Would you mind upvoting the answer if it solved your question?